# Convert varbinary data into xlsx file using aws sdk and nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, amazon-s3

I'm working on a code that will pull `varbinary` data from an SQL Server table which will then be placed into an s3 bucket. The code works for most file types except xlsx files.

```
request.query(` select <varbinarydata> from <table> , (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                mssql.close();
                throw (err);
            }
            else {
                var filename = <DocumentNm>
                var varbdatan = new Buffer(data.recordset[0].<varbinarydata>);     
                s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: <S3 Bucket>
                    Key: filename,
                    Body: varbdatan
                }, err => {
                    if (err) {
                        mssql.close();
                        throw (err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Data Successfully Inserted');
                        mssql.close();
                        callback(null, 1);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I've tried including contenttype in the code but the code works without it for other files.

Is there some sort of additional conversion needed for xlsx files?

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the ContentType param on putObject. If you use NodeJS to save the varbinary data to a local file instead can you open that local file in Excel? Just trying to determine if it's S3 breaking the file data or if it's already broken in SQL.

Comment: Due to the way our DB server is set up, it can only be accessed by the AWS Lambda function and directly insert the data to the S3 bucket. Can't create the file locally, unfortunately

Comment: I've determined that it is s3 that is breaking the data. The file can be created locally if I get the buffer data